# adding string to one column and numbers to another column

Tags: matlab, matrix

I need a matrix with numbers in one column and strings in another column in matlab

```
a = [ 1 'cancer'
      2 'cancer'
      3 'cancer'
      4 'noncancer'
      5 'noncancer' ]
```

I am unable to add strings to an array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a cell array. To do so, just replace the square brackets by curly brackets:

```
a = { 1 'cancer'
      2 'cancer'
      3 'cancer'
      4 'noncancer'
      5 'noncancer' }
```

This results in

```
a = 

    [1]    'cancer'   
    [2]    'cancer'   
    [3]    'cancer'   
    [4]    'noncancer'
    [5]    'noncancer'
```

Comment: That works. How to do it for 150 data. Is it possible to do it with a for loop. I have to type manually for 150 data as above.

Comment: That depends on how your data look like. I would suppose you have a vector with numbers and a vector with strings?

Comment: Thank you for the information. Now I got it with a for loop with cell structure.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to use is not the array but the [cell](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/ref/cell.html) data structure

[A link that asks the same question as yours](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/comp.soft-sys.matlab/44hwtt_31aQ)

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer with loop

```
clc;clear all;close all;

count = 0
for i = 1 : 5
    count = count + 1;
    a{i,1} = count;
end



for i=1:3
    a{i,2} = ['cancer'];
end
for i=4:5
    a{i,2} = ['noncancer'];
end
```

Comment: Consider pre-allocating memory for your cell array prior to initialization (in your case, that would be done in the following way: `a = cell(5, 2);`). This avoids dynamic allocation, which can slow down execution significantly for large arrays.

Comment: @EitanT Thank you. I would use it for my large array, which has 150 data.